# Can default in switch case return to cin?

Tags: c++

Under default can I make the code return to the "cin>>op;" in the first line?

Note: The text under cout is in my language it isnt anything important I can't bother changing it..

```
 cin>>op;
switch(op)
{
case '+' :
    cout<<"Odbravte sobiranje"<<endl;
    cout<<"Rezultatot je"<<a+b<<endl;
case '-' :
    cout<<"Odbravte odzemanje"<<endl;
    cout<<"Rezultatot je"<<a-b<<endl;
case '*' :
    cout<<"Odbravte mnozenje"<<endl;
    cout<<"Rezultatot je"<<a*b<<endl;
case '/' :
    cout<<"Odbravte delenje"<<endl;
    cout<<"Rezultatot je"<<a/b<<endl;
default:
    cout<<"Vnesovte netocen podatok"<<endl;
    cout<<"Obidete se povtorno"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What about using a loop with a `bool` variable indicating the input was expected? Also you should use `break` after each handled case.

Comment: The occasional `break` might be nice :(

Comment: alternative to a loop, you can use a `goto` statement

Comment: @khuderm you could, but that is rarely recommended if a loop can handle the job. `goto`s have a lot of gotchas for the unwary, and even if the `goto` is used correctly you often wind up dealing with all of the questions and admonishments using one brings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here:

First, you don't have `break` statements at the end of your cases, so the program will "fall through" to the next case. This means that entering "+" will print all four operations as well as the default case. Fix this by adding `break` statements.

Second, you can loop using one of the looping control statements in C++. I'd recommend a `while` loop in this case along with an exit flag.

So your code would end up looking like this:

```
bool keep_looping = true;
while(keep_looping)
{
    cin>>op;
    switch(op)
    {
        case '+' :
            cout<<"Odbravte sobiranje"<<endl;
            cout<<"Rezultatot je"<<a+b<<endl;
            keep_looping = false; // <-- this will prevent the while loop from looping
            break; // <-- break statements prevent fallthrough to the next ccase
        case '-' :
            cout<<"Odbravte odzemanje"<<endl;
            cout<<"Rezultatot je"<<a-b<<endl;
            keep_looping = false;
            break;
        case '*' :
            cout<<"Odbravte mnozenje"<<endl;
            cout<<"Rezultatot je"<<a*b<<endl;
            keep_looping = false;
            break;
        case '/' :
            cout<<"Odbravte delenje"<<endl;
            cout<<"Rezultatot je"<<a/b<<endl;
            keep_looping = false;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Vnesovte netocen podatok"<<endl;
            cout<<"Obidete se povtorno"<<endl;
            break;
    }
}

cout << "Done the while loop" << endl;
```

The `while` loop will keep looping until its condition becomes false. In this case, we set the `keep_looping` variable to false when a valid operation is entered.

Comment: Inverting the logic of your `bool` variable could reduce the logic to be handled in the `default` case solely.

Comment: I presented it this way so that there are less logic inversions to deal with for a beginner.

Comment: Better teach beginners the right way from the beginning ;-) . To make the logic clear, you could consider to name the `bool` variable differently.